# TikZ matrices shifting with fill and text inside a node

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I am trying to create a checkerboard in LaTeX. I use TikZ's matrix for the task. It works if there's only text or only fills in the matrix. However, when I use both text and matrix, everything start shifting weirdly. How can I fix this?

Below is the code I'm using and its output.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
%This one is the problematic one
\begin{minipage}{0.32\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[xstep=1cm,ystep=1,color=gray] (0,0) grid (4,4);
    \matrix[matrix of nodes,
    inner sep=0pt,
    anchor=south west,
    nodes={inner sep=0pt,text width=1cm,align=center,minimum height=1cm}
    ]{
        |[fill=black!255]| & A & |[fill=black!255]| & \\
        & |[fill=black!255]| & B & |[fill=black!255]| \\
        |[fill=black!255]| & C & |[fill=black!255]| & \\
        & |[fill=black!255]| & D & |[fill=black!255]| \\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
% Nothing's wrong if I only add text and fill on the highest layer
\begin{minipage}{0.32\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[xstep=1cm,ystep=1,color=gray] (0,0) grid (4,4);
    \matrix[matrix of nodes,
    inner sep=0pt,
    anchor=south west,
    nodes={inner sep=0pt,text width=1cm,align=center,minimum height=1cm}
    ]{
        |[fill=black!255]| & A &   & \\
         &   & B & \\
         & C &   & \\
         &   & D & \\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
% Also, everything's okay if there are only fills with no text
\begin{minipage}{0.32\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[xstep=1cm,ystep=1,color=gray] (0,0) grid (4,4);
    \matrix[matrix of nodes,
    inner sep=0pt,
    anchor=south west,
    nodes={inner sep=0pt,text width=1cm,align=center,minimum height=1cm}
    ]{
        |[fill=black!255]| & & |[fill=black!255]| & \\
        & |[fill=black!255]| & & |[fill=black!255]| \\
        |[fill=black!255]| & & |[fill=black!255]| & \\
        & |[fill=black!255]| & & |[fill=black!255]| \\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image: Compiled output of the code]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my way. I add something: `[anchor=center]`, `[nodes in empty cells]`, `c/.style`, `[row sep=-\pgflinewidth]`, `[column sep=-\pgflinewidth]`;
and remove some unnecessary options.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{c/.style={fill=yellow}}
\tikzset{mystyle/.style={matrix of nodes,
        nodes in empty cells,
        row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        nodes={draw,minimum width=1cm,minimum height=1cm,anchor=center}}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[mystyle]{
|[c]|&A    &|[c]|&\\
     &|[c]|&B    &|[c]|\\
|[c]|&C    &|[c]|&\\
     &|[c]|&D    &|[c]|\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[mystyle]{
|[c]|&    &|[c]|&\\
&|[c]|&    &|[c]|\\
|[c]|&    &|[c]|&\\
&|[c]|&    &|[c]|\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[mystyle]{
&A    &&\\
&&B    &\\
&C    &&\\
&&D    &\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

For first `minipage`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of nodes,
         nodes in empty cells,  % <---
         nodes={minimum size=1cm, anchor=center,
                inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt},
         draw, inner sep=0pt
        ]
{
|[fill]| & A        & |[fill]|  &           \\
         & |[fill]| & B         & |[fill]|  \\
|[fill]| & C        & |[fill]|  &           \\
         & |[fill]| & D         & |[fill]| \\
};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Just a little change on Zarko's answer. It's possible to define the chess board combining row and columns style, without having to specifically `fill` the desired cells.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of nodes,
         nodes in empty cells,  % <---
         every odd column/.style={every odd row/.append style={nodes={fill=black}}},
         every even column/.style={every even row/.append style={nodes={fill=black}}},
         nodes={minimum size=1cm, anchor=center,
                inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt},
         draw, inner sep=0pt
        ]
{
 & A &   &  \\
 &   & B &  \\
 & C &   &  \\
 &   & D &  \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]